# Delegates usage in C++/CLI

Tags: .net, visual-studio, function, delegates, intellisense

I'm trying to use Delegate in C++/Cli, I referred [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s0tkKZoMN1Y) video which is in C#

```
#include <iostream>
#include"stdafx.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;


public ref class Employee
{
public:
    Employee() {};
    ~Employee() {};
public:
    int ID;
    String ^name;
    int Salary;
    int Experience;

public: static void Promote(List<Employee^>^ members,promoteDelegate^ promo)
{
    for each (Employee ^emp in members)
    {
        if(promo(emp))
        Console::WriteLine("{0} is Promoted", emp->name);
    }
}

};

delegate bool promoteDelegate(Employee^ emp);

ref class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass() {};
    ~MyClass() {};

static bool func(Employee^ emp)
{
    return (emp->Salary >= 5000);
}

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    List<Employee^> ^Employee_List = gcnew List<Employee^>;
    Employee^ emp1 = gcnew Employee;
    emp1->name = "Ajanth"; emp1->ID = 0;emp1->Salary = 50000;emp1->Experience = 3;

    Employee^ emp2 = gcnew Employee;
    emp2->name = "Aman"; emp2->ID = 1;emp2->Salary = 45000;emp2->Experience = 9;

    Employee^ emp3 = gcnew Employee;
    emp3->name = "Ashish"; emp3->ID = 2;emp3->Salary = 60000;emp3->Experience = 4;

    Employee_List->Add(emp1);
    Employee_List->Add(emp2);
    Employee_List->Add(emp3);

    promoteDelegate ^promoDel = gcnew promoteDelegate(func);

    Employee::Promote(Employee_List, promoDel); //Error here
    return 0;
}
};
```

I'm getting compiler error as below

> 'Employee::Promote' does not take 2 arguments. function "Employee::Promote" cannot be called with the given argument list.
>  argument types are: (System::Collections::Generic::List ^, promoteDelegate ^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always start from the **top** of the error list.  Later messages get increasingly less reliable.  First error you'll get is for the Promote() function definition, the compiler does not yet know what `promoteDelegate` means.  Which then causes more errors, like the one you quoted.

Important rule to keep in mind is that, very unlike C#, the C++ compiler uses single-pass compilation.  All types must be declared before they are used.  That can be pretty awkward, like it is here, since the delegate type itself uses the Employee type.  A chicken-and-egg problem that must be solved with a *forward declaration*:

```
ref class Employee;    // Forward declaration
public delegate bool promoteDelegate(Employee^ emp);

public ref class Employee
{
   // etc..
}
```

Fix your #includes as well, stdafx.h must always be included first.